# Search page in spring mvc doesn't work

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I Have created simple mvc CRUD. All works fine except search page.

Im getting errorr as follows:

**HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0**

Controller page is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search")  
    public ModelAndView search(){
    return new ModelAndView("search","command", new Emp());  
      } 

    @RequestMapping(value="/jsp/searchemp",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
    public ModelAndView search1(@ModelAttribute("name") Emp emp){      
        String name = null;
        name = dao.searchname(name);
    return new ModelAndView("searchemp","name",name);  
    }
```

Search.jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>z    
<html>
<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <style>

     label {
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
}   
.box{background-color: #e1e8f0;}
body{background:#f0eceb;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="  left: 30%;   top: 25%;  position: absolute;">
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-3  box "  > 

       <center> <h1>Add New Employee</h1>  </center>
         <form method="post" action="jsp/searchemp/"  >

           <div class="form-group">  <div class="col-xs-7">     
          <label  ><h5>Name    :</h5></label>       
           <input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name of the employee"  />
           <button type="submit" value="Save"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search</button>
         </div></div>


         </form> 
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </head>
```

Searchemp.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

<div class="container"> 
   <h1>Employees List</h1>  
<table class="table table-hover" border="1" width="70%" cellpadding="2"> 
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th><th>Designation</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr></thead> 

   <tbody><tr>  
   <td>${String.id}</td>  
   <td>${String.name}</td>  
   <td>${emp.salary}</td>  
   <td>${emp.designation}</td>  
   <td><a href="editemp/${emp.id}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.id}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  </tbody>

   </table>  
   <br/>  
   <a href="empform">Add New Employee</a>
```

jdbctemplate query:

public String searchname(String name) {

```
    String query = "select * from Emp99 where name=?"; 
    Object[] inputs = new Object[] {name};
    String empName = template.queryForObject(query, inputs, String.class);
    return empName;
}
```

Dont know what goes wrong.
help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order for jsp to consume an bean , your controller method should return data,in your jsp you are trying to utilize 
    `{String.id}`  and `{emp.id}` which is never passed from the controller method `search1`.so you need to add your beans to a model and 
    return the page like this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/jsp/searchemp",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String search1(@ModelAttribute("name") Emp emp,Model model){      
  model.addAttribute("emp",emp); //passing the model name and the bean , 
  //model.addAttribute("name",anotherBean); //you can add many attributes as you wish.
  return "searchemp";
}
```

now inside the `searchemp.jsp` you can utilize  the emp bean like this.
    `{emp.id}`
    remove the `{String.id}` part. inside the `searchemp.jsp` which will not work.

Comment: Thanks For the help.It works.Now the Search Page is connected but im getting all records in the database.how can I search for the specific records only.

Comment: I Changed the my content in searchemp.jsp as <c:forEach var="emp" items="${id}">   and in controller as  @RequestMapping(value="/jsp/searchemp/{id}")    
        public ModelAndView search(@PathVariable int id){     
        return new ModelAndView("searchemp","id",id);  
        }          But It displays empty record.

Comment: you cant iterate over  `${id}`. it is not a collection it's just a bean. remove the for each part.in `searchemp.jsp` you are supposed to utilize an list not an single object.take a look at the search method it returns a `list`.

Comment: in order to represent the `${id}` you can use `${id}` or if bean contain any properties then use `${id.propName}`

Comment: Edited the post pls see that ,correceted the previous mistakes but still error occurs.

Comment: edited the post. you seriously need to take a look at how Model works in Spring

Comment: now i rewriten all the codes with new controller and jabc template .Im getting error TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback;

Comment: Dont edit the same question over and over again. Now my answer doesnt makes any sense. I might even get downvoted.

Comment: sry for the in covinience i have asked it in a new question pls see that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922603/transientdataaccessresourceexception-preparedstatementcallback

Comment: roll backed the question..pls see the question in the link